# Error: Package doesn't exists when importing a user defined package from a class

Tags: java, syntax-error, static-variables

Here My first file code

```
package com.shubham.packages.a;

import static com.shubham.packages.b.Message.Hello;

public class Greeting {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println("Hello World");
     Hello();
   }
}
```

Here my second file code

```
package com.shubham.packages.b;

public class Message {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      
    }
    public static void Hello() {
        System.out.println("This is Awesome.");
    }
}
```

Here the error I got when I run the program.
[image: Terminal Image]

Comment: You really should put the text of your error messages in your question, instead of just an image.

Answer (score 0):

When you compile your code javac needs to know where to look for all of your source/class files. You could go to "java_tutorial" folder and run.

```
javac com/shubham/packages/a/Greeting.java com/shubham/packages/b/Message.java
```

That should compile both of your java files into class files at the same location. Then you should be able to run.

```
java com.shubham.packages.a.Greeting
```

**I might be using the wrong slashes for windows**

You can explicitly name all of the necessary java files, so this should cause both Greeting.java and Message.java to be compiled in place.

When you run java, the CWD is on the classpath by default so that means the package com.shubham.packages.a and ...b should be on the classpath in their correct location.

A slightly better way to do this is to create a folder called "build" or whatever you like.

```
javac -d build com/shubham/packages/a/Greeting.java com/shubham/packages/b/Message.java
```

That will output the class files to the build folder. Then when you run it.

```
java -cp build com.shubham.packages.a.Greeting
```